# "Northwest" vs "northwestern"

Tags: word-usage

Which of these two word should I use when I want to say something like that:

> My hometown is located in the northwest Italy (or another county's name in general)

or

> My hometown is located in the northwestern Italy (or another county's name in general)

Which is the difference between "Northwest" and "northwestern"?

Comment: I think that the first sentence would be correct if you took out the 'the' so it reads, 'My hometown is located in northwest Italy.' Or you could say 'the northwestern part of Italy.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All compass directions are **nouns** - north, south, east, west, and all those in-between such as northwest, southeast etc.

"*Northwestern*" and all similar words like southern, eastern, southwestern etc are **adjectives**.

Using the *noun* you could say:

- I live in the northwest **of** Italy
- I live in Northwest Italy.

In this particular example, "[Northwest Italy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northwest_Italy)" is the official name for one of the five regions of Italy, so for that reason, it requires capitalisation as it is a proper noun.

Using the adjective you could say:

- I live in the *northwestern area* of Italy
- I live in the *northwestern part* of Italy

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/northwest) also marks 'northwest' as an adjective